# Why Google cant see and index my root page from Sitemap?

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I will firstly ask a question and below the question you will see an explanation.

Can you tell me where is the actual issue in indexing, is my Sitemap correctly set up, and how do I solve this problem so my Root-page can be indexed properly and seen in Sitemap by Google?

===================================================

The SEO on my webpage is very good set up and maintained. Somehow I found out by manually indexing my root page, that my root page is not indexed from Sitemap (even if it of course exists in sitemap) but from other other intern and extern links, where none of them is real (canonical) root URL.

So, in URL inspection in Webmastertools for Sitemap is shown as N/A,
and as a Referring Page (my root-page is https://www.example.ca):

```
1. https://www.example.ca/tag/some-folder-name/index21.html?PageSpeed=noscript
2. https://www.example.com/
3. http://www.example.ca/
4. http://s709358732.online.de/terms-of-use.html (old server replacement domain)
```

I also want to say something about my Sitemap. My Sitemap is on the link:

```
https://www.example.ca/sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

And it looks like this:

```
<sitemapindex>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://www.example.ca/sitemap/sitemap_pages1.xml
</loc>
<lastmod>2021-03-21T01:41:20+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://www.example.ca/sitemap/sitemap_categories1.xml
</loc>
<lastmod>2021-03-21T01:41:20+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://www.example.ca/sitemap/sitemap_accounts1.xml
</loc>
<lastmod>2021-03-21T01:41:20+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://www.example.ca/sitemap/sitemap_news1.xml
</loc>
<lastmod>2021-03-21T01:41:20+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://www.example.ca/sitemap/sitemap_listings1.xml
</loc>
<lastmod>2021-03-21T01:41:20+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>
https://www.example.ca/sitemap/sitemap_locations1.xml
</loc>
<lastmod>2021-03-21T01:41:20+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

My rootpage in the sitemap is in the

```
https://www.example.ca/sitemap/sitemap_pages1.xml
```

And here is a Screenshot from the Webmastertools to get full understanding what i am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Google almost never indexes pages because it finds them in an XML sitemap.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).

Comment: How long has your site been online and these sitemaps been available?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for participating. My website is over 6 years online, but these sitemaps I have are published before about 2 years, since I started using a new script which has such Sitemap structure. I was just blown away knowing that Google does not see my rootpage on them.

Comment: It looks like your page is indexed.  Are you sure that URL is exactly what appears in the sitemap?   The sitemap has the `www`, has `https`, and doesn't have `/index.html`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller 100% sure, i have excelent SEO which is very good maintained, all duplicates are redirectedd to https and www

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. I'm not sure why Google doesn't say that it's listed in the site map. However, it doesn't look like anything to worry about. Google search console is not very reliable about what data it shows in my experience.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i appreciate your time sir.

Answer (score 3):

Sitemaps are only valid for [pages that appear below them in the site hierarchy.](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap):

> A sitemap can be posted anywhere on your site, but a sitemap affects only descendants of the parent directory. Therefore, a sitemap posted at the site root can affect all files on the site, which is where we recommend posting your sitemaps.

By putting your sitemap in a `/sitemap/` folder you are limiting it to only that folder and it's descendants.

They should ideally be in the root of your site.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your participation. Your answer does make sense, specially for the reason  Google says what you said above. However do you think 1. this issue is a caused by only false Sitemap, 2. all main pages should be in Sitemap.xml file (and not other named Sitemap file), 3. should all generated pages in sitemap ordered in hierarchy and not separate sitemap with another name, as it is the case in my sitemap? Thanks.

Comment: Your sitemaps need to be in the root of your site, and then the search console should list the pages as being in the sitemap. You can certainly create a sitemap index file and point to multiple sitemaps, but the same rules for location and hierarchy apply.